# LibGdx Tools Error

Tags: java, intellij-idea, opengl-es, libgdx

I have problem with building my Core/Desktop/Android project in IntelliJ after adding gxd-tools.jar as Core Library.

Please note my imports:

```
package com.enplug.exampleapp;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException;
import com.enplug.common.logging.ILog;
import com.enplug.sdk.hosting.AppState;
import com.enplug.sdk.hosting.HostedGame;
import com.enplug.sdk.interfaces.FontType;
import com.enplug.sdk.interfaces.IServiceProvider;
import com.enplug.sdk.model.social.SocialFeedDefinition;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.freetype.*;

import com.badlogic.gdx.tools.imagepacker.TexturePacker2;
```

and TexturePacker code:

```
 TexturePacker2.process("C:\\pokusatlas", "C:\\pokusatlas", "spritesheet");
```

Screenshot of my error:

[image: gdx-tools compilation errir]

What should I make to avoid this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the guide about [adding libgdx tools to the gradle dependencies](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Dependency-management-with-Gradle#tools-gradle). Let me quote the important part:

> Tools Gradle
>
> Core Dependency:
>
> Dont put me in core!

==> you should not add gdx tools to core project! Put it in desktop project instead:

```
 compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-tools:$gdxVersion"
```

The issue with adding libgdx-tools to core project is that the libgdx-tools are not compatible with android/ios projects. But android/ios depend on core project, so you cannot add plattform-dependent libs to your core project.

But even if it would be possible to include in core project it wouldn't be a good idea either. I mean you are not going to run TexturePacker in your released apps anyway. Just run TexturePacker during development and include its output in your android assets folder.